# 実行途中からSDカードに画像が保存できなくなります。

Tags: spresense, ニューラルネットワーク

SPRESENSEとその拡張ボード、カメラ、ニューラルネットワークコンソールで作成した判定モデルを用いて、下記のようなプログラムを作成し、実行しています。ただし、下記(1)～(5)を繰り返し連続して実行すると3周目からは、SDカードに画像が保存できなくなります。原因と対処方法についてアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？

(1)カメラで撮影
(2)画像を3つに分割・リサイズし、それぞれをSDカードに保存（pgm形式）
(3)続けて、そのSDカードに保存した画像の1つをオープンし、ニューラルネットワークに入力
(4)画像を判定
(5)上記(3)と(4)を残りの2つの画像についても繰り返し実施

ちなみに、ニューラルネットワークへの入力（判定）をやめると、保存は出来ます。
また、分割した画像のうち1つだけSDカードに保存するように変更すると
6周目までは、正常に保存できるようになります（7周目でNG）

Arduino IDEを使って実装しており、メモリは1280KBを選択しています。

他にも必要な情報があればご説明しますが、ひとまず、上記についてご助言いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「SDカードに画像が保存できなくなります」というのは、(1)SDカードに空きがなくなって保存できなくなる、(2)SDカードには十分に空きがあるのに保存できなくなる、のどちらですか？
また、(3)(4)の動作をさせることで、(2)でSDに保存した画像ファイル（pgm形式）の大きさが変わったりしますか？

Comment: まあたいていは有限個しかないリソースを閉じていないせいですよね（組み込み系だと同時に開けるファイル数が極端に少なかったりします）

Comment: @junkun0804 さん
ソースコードを載せることはできますか？
ソースコードを乗せてもらった方が問題点が明確になりやすいと思います。